# Selenium web driver open a new tab in an existing window, which is already opened

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My requirement is such that first time when I run my code, it should open a new window log in and get data, second time when I run the program it should use the same window and open a new tab, so that the user need not log in once again , I read that we can open new tabs from existing window, but when I run the program its opening a new window every time, but I want my webdriver to use the same window which was opened the first time when the program was run. Is it possible ?

Comment: You should use Testng or Junit annotation to achive this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible, but why do you want to run your program, exit it and run it again?
Just run your program and log in, then do the next steps.

If you are running the program as a unit test, you could do the login as a @BeforeTest (testng) or @Before (junit), and then do the other actions in your @Test methods.